# How to put data in a Python package using setup.cfg

Tags: python-3.x, package, setuptools

I'm trying to create a package with with a data file, but it's not working.

My setup.cfg (per [link](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html)) is below.

```
[metadata]
name = my_package
version = 1.0.0
description = My package description
author = John Henckel
author_email = henckel.jonathan@mayo.edu
url = http://example.com
keywords = one, two
license = BSD 3-Clause License
classifiers =
    Framework :: Django
    License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5

[options]
include_package_data = True
packages = find:

[options.package_data]
* = *.txt
```

and the directory structure of my project is...

```
LICENSE
pyproject.toml
README.md
setup.cfg
my_package
    hello.txt
    __init__.py
```

and I typed...

```
python -m build --sdist
tar -vtf dist/my_package-1.0.0.tar.gz
```

and the output, as you can see **does not** contain the `hello.txt`.   WHY NOT!??

```
drwxrwxrwx  0 0      0           0 Oct 22 17:28 my_package-1.0.0/
-rw-rw-rw-  0 0      0          48 Oct 22 17:24 my_package-1.0.0/LICENSE
-rw-rw-rw-  0 0      0         474 Oct 22 17:28 my_package-1.0.0/PKG-INFO
-rw-rw-rw-  0 0      0          29 Oct 22 17:24 my_package-1.0.0/README.md
drwxrwxrwx  0 0      0           0 Oct 22 17:28 my_package-1.0.0/my_package/
-rw-rw-rw-  0 0      0           0 Oct 22 17:24 my_package-1.0.0/my_package/__init__.py
drwxrwxrwx  0 0      0           0 Oct 22 17:28 my_package-1.0.0/my_package.egg-info/
-rw-rw-rw-  0 0      0         474 Oct 22 17:28 my_package-1.0.0/my_package.egg-info/PKG-INFO
-rw-rw-rw-  0 0      0         201 Oct 22 17:28 my_package-1.0.0/my_package.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
-rw-rw-rw-  0 0      0           1 Oct 22 17:28 my_package-1.0.0/my_package.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
-rw-rw-rw-  0 0      0          11 Oct 22 17:28 my_package-1.0.0/my_package.egg-info/top_level.txt
-rw-rw-rw-  0 0      0         108 Oct 01 13:52 my_package-1.0.0/pyproject.toml
-rw-rw-rw-  0 0      0         528 Oct 22 17:28 my_package-1.0.0/setup.cfg
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that this might depend on which version of setuptools you have installed. When I build a test version of your package, using the same `setup.cfg`, my source distribution contains `hello.txt`. However, you may also want to try removing the `include_package_data = True` option from `setup.cfg`. The latest [setuptools user guide](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html) says the following:

"In summary, the three options allow you to:

- `include_package_data`
  Accept all data files and directories matched by MANIFEST.in.
- `package_data` Specify additional patterns to match files that may or may not be matched by MANIFEST.in or found in source control.
- `exclude_package_data` Specify patterns for data files and directories that should not be included when a package is installed, even if they would otherwise have been included due to the use of the preceding options."

It may be that, for some versions of `setuptools`, the `include_package_data` option overrides the `package_data` list so that you have to supply a `MANIFEST.in` file instead.

Edit: I overlooked this statement in the setuptools user guide, which seems to confirm what I wrote above:

"If using the setuptools-specific `include_package_data` argument, files specified by package_data will not be automatically added to the manifest unless they are listed in the MANIFEST.in file."

Comment: Since a lot of packages are currently being converted to use pyproject.toml, it might be helpful to know if my answer works for others as well.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. In order to include `hello.txt` in the package, it is necessary to remove the line that says `include_package_data = True`.  Not very intuitive!  but I can see why it is this way, because of historical reasons.  THANKS